# recommandation webpage/book  to learn asmd chart over using verilog

Tags: verilog, digital-logic, hdl

I have searched so many website to take background about how asm chart is used in verilog code.However, I could not find any web cite with sufficient examples to learn asm chart. Can anyone give or recommend any website/book which I can be similar with asm chart implemented over using verilog?

Comment: answering your own question is an accepted practice, for those that wonder. This does seem like a very narrow question though. Is this going to really be of long term value to the site and community on the whole?

Comment: I think, it will help because lack of webcite push us to look other source. The topic asmd chart is important part of the digital design and It should be learned very well, but I have not seen any book except below one and webpage which express it with verilog code. When I found a one, I want share this link, not for  getting  a vote.

Comment: would it not be better to use this site to ask questions related to issues you engage then attempt to create lists of books? We are slowly becoming a source for dealing with many technical issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a book and in it there are so many example about how asmd chart can be implemented using Verilog HDL: *FPGA Prototyping By Verilog Examples: Xilinx Spartan-3 Version* by Pong P. Chu ([Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470185325)).